# How to Delete Item in Sitecore and Update All References

Tags: c#, sitecore8

I need to programmatically delete items in Sitecore, but if they are being referenced by other items, then I need to update those items to reference some other item.

In the UI, Sitecore provides a dialog box for doing this, but the `item.Delete()` and `item.Recycle()` methods don't appear to have any overrides for something similar. I can use `Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(item, true)` to get the referring items, but I would still need to get the specific fields from those items and update them according to their type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, as long as the item's ID gets replaced in the referring item's field, the field's type shouldn't matter. One exception would be the Rich Text field type, where links in the HTML have the following format:

```html
<a href="-/media/somelowercaseguidwithouthyphens.ashx"></a>
```

So we should be able to do two simple replacements. One for the item ID and one for the lower-cased, unhyphenated ID.

First, get the referring item links, and create the replacement strings.

```cs
var links = Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(item, true);

string oldIdWithoutBraces = item.ID.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
string newIdWithoutBraces = newItem.ID.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
string oldIdForHyperlinks = oldIdWithoutBraces.ToLower().Replace("-", "");
string newIdForHyperlinks = newIdWithoutBraces.ToLower().Replace("-", "");
```

Then, for each referring item link, get its referring field and update the item IDs in it.

```cs
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
        var sourceItem = link.GetSourceItem();
        var fieldId = link.SourceFieldID;
        var field = sourceItem.Fields[fieldId];

        sourceItem.Editing.BeginEdit();

        try
        {
            field.Value = field.Value
                .Replace(oldIdWithoutBraces, newIdWithoutBraces)
                .Replace(oldIdForHyperlinks, newIdForHyperlinks);
        }
        catch
        {
            sourceItem.Editing.CancelEdit();
        }
        finally
        {
            sourceItem.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

Afterward, the original item can be deleted.

```cs
item.Recycle();
```

Some Sitecore field types (such as Image fields) have a `path` attribute, which should be updated as well, but it shouldn't be difficult to work that into the code above.